ActiveMQ Artemis web console Keycloak integration issue
The Keycloak instance is version 25.0.6, running on-site. I'm trying to run ActiveMQ Artemis console with Keycloack integration and getting the following error:
[hawtio-auth-keycloak] Failed to initialise Keycloak: u[hawtio-auth-keycloak] Failed to initialise Keycloak:

and console page goes into endless reload.
I added *.jar libraries for Keycloak, but futile.
Keycloak ver: 25.0.6
Dockerfile:
FROM jetty:12.0.14-jre21
RUN java -jar /usr/local/jetty/start.jar --add-modules=ee10-deploy
RUN curl -s -S https://dlcdn.apache.org/activemq/activemq-artemis-console/1.0.0/apache-artemis-console-1.0.0-bin.tar.gz | tar -xvz -C /tmp && \
    mv /tmp/apache-artemis-console-1.0.0/artemis-console-war.war /var/lib/jetty/webapps && \
    chown jetty:jetty /var/lib/jetty/webapps/artemis-console-war.war && \
    rm -rf /tmp/apache-artemis-console-1.0.0 && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-core/25.0.6/keycloak-core-25.0.6.jar --output-dir /usr/local/jetty/lib && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-server-spi-private/25.0.6/keycloak-server-spi-private-25.0.6.jar --output-dir /usr/local/jetty/lib && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-server-spi/25.0.6/keycloak-server-spi-25.0.6.jar --output-dir /usr/local/jetty/lib && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-crypto-default/25.0.6/keycloak-crypto-default-25.0.6.jar --output-dir /usr/local/jetty/lib && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-common/25.0.6/keycloak-common-25.0.6.jar --output-dir /usr/local/jetty/lib && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-adapter-core/25.0.3/keycloak-adapter-core-25.0.3.jar --output-dir /usr/local/jetty/lib && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-jetty-adapter-spi/25.0.3/keycloak-jetty-adapter-spi-25.0.3.jar --output-dir /usr/local/jetty/lib && \
    curl -O https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/keycloak/keycloak-jetty-core/25.0.3/keycloak-jetty-core-25.0.3.jar --output-dir /usr/local/jetty/lib
COPY --chown=jetty:jetty Docker/artemis-console/artemis-console.xml /var/lib/jetty/webapps
EXPOSE 8080

hawtio-oidc.properties
keycloak.realm = dev
keycloak.resource = wt-activemq-console
keycloak.auth-server-url = https://company-keycloak/auth
keycloak.ssl-required = external
keycloak.public-client = true
keycloak.principal-attribute = preferred_username
keycloak.credentials.secret = keycloak-secret

keycloak-bearer.json
{
    "realm": "dev",
    "resource": "wt-activemq-console",
    "auth-server-url": "https://company-keycloak/auth",
    "principal-attribute": "preferred_username",
    "use-resource-role-mappings": false,
    "ssl-required": "external",
    "confidential-port": 0,
    "credentials" : {
        "secret" : "keycloak-secret"
    }
}

keycloak-hawtio.json
{
    "realm": "dev",
    "clientId": "wt-activemq-console",
    "url": "https://company-keycloak/auth"
}

login.config
console {
    org.keycloak.adapters.jaas.BearerTokenLoginModule required
        keycloak-config-file="/usr/local/jetty/etc/keycloak-bearer.json"
        role-principal-class=org.apache.activemq.artemis.spi.core.security.jaas.RolePrincipal
    ;
};





you need to provide the minimal, reproducible example if not you to address your question?

the error seems about JS part of the console. I have tried to build console, from repository: https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis-console - but the console does not work. Only errors I've got are:
2024-12-04 16:57:09.872:WARN :oejes.ServletChannelState:qtp315138752-25: unhandled due to prior sendError
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Closed
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.HttpOutput.checkWritable(HttpOutput.java:701)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.ee10.servlet.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:731)
        at java.base/java.io.OutputStream.write(Unknown Source)

